# strings in C- is char *str is really equivalent to char str []?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between char *str="STRING" and char str[] = "STRING"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string)
>   [Need some help with C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268292/need-some-help-with-c-programming)

while this snip gets segmentation fault

```
int main(void) {

    char*  str ="abcde";
    str[strlen(str)-1] ='\0';
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

If I put
 `char str [] ="abcde";` instead of the pointer that works perfectly, do you have an idea why so?

Comment: The title of your question and its body ask different things.

Comment: By the way, this gets asked every week. Please do some research before posting here.

Comment: @Bertrand - I looked for a dupe before answering, but couldn't find anything good enough to vote to close for. Can you link to the "definitive" answer on this?

Comment: @awoodland, how many do you want?

Comment: @Bertrand - just *the* definitive one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880573/c-difference-between-char-var-and-char-var http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268292/need-some-help-with-c-programming  There is not much to say for such a question.

Comment: The answers are good on the proposed duplicate, but the code example is needlessly complex

Comment: Please close this, really. Or close the others as a dupe of this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `char *str = "abcde";` you make a `char` pointer to a string literal, which you are not allowed to modify.

When you write `char str[] = "abcde";` you make a `char` array and copy a string literal into it. This is just a normal `char` array so you are free to modify it.

It is undefined behaviour to modify a string literal. This is a deliberate design decision that allows string literals to be placed in special read only sections of the output program. In practice many compliers and platforms do this (marking it read only means you need only one copy of the strings in memory, even if there is more than one instance of the program running). This leads to the behaviour you observed on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str = "abcde";
```

`str` is a pointer to char that points to a string literal. String literals are stored in read only memory. You can't modify them.

```
char str[] = "abcde";
```

The string literal `"abcde"` is copied into the array `str`. So you can modify it.

Comment: string literals **can** stored in read only memory

Answer (score 1):

`char *` is pointer to char (string literal) and `char []` is an array of char. You can't modify string literal but you can modify char array.