# How to declare strings in C

Tags: c, string

Can anyone explain me what is a difference between these lines of code

```
char *p = "String";
char p2[] = "String";
char p3[7] = "String";
```

In what case should I use each of the above ?

Comment: Well that last one is a buffer overflow, so that's nice.

Comment: You third example should be `p3[6]`: you must account for the final 0

Comment: @fge: needs 7 in fact.

Comment: @Dan compilation error, rather

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880573/c-difference-between-char-var-and-char-var  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268292/need-some-help-with-c-programming  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[This link](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html) should satisfy your curiosity.

Basically (forgetting your third example which is bad), the different between 1 and 2 is that 1 allocates space for a pointer to the array.

But in the code, you can manipulate them as pointers all the same -- only thing, you cannot reallocate the second.

Comment: guys, before you bookmark the link that fge posted, be aware that FAQ website has been updated to this http://c-faq.com and the specific link posted to this http://c-faq.com/aryptr (2.1,2.2) but without changes. Just in case.

Answer (score 50):

Strings in C are represented as arrays of characters.

```
char *p = "String";
```

You are declaring a pointer that points to a string stored some where in your program (modifying this string is undefined behavior) according to the C programming language 2 ed.

```
char p2[] = "String";
```

You are declaring an array of char initialized with the string "String" leaving to the compiler the job to count the size of the array.

```
char p3[5] = "String";
```

You are declaring an array of size 5 and initializing it with "String". This is an error be cause "String" don't fit in 5 elements.

`char p3[7] = "String";` is the correct declaration ('\0' is the terminating character in c strings).

http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html

Comment: Just a note that the link has been updated to http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html

Answer (score 22):

You shouldn't use the third one because its wrong. "String" takes 7 bytes, not 5.

The first one is a pointer (can be reassigned to a different address), the other two are declared as arrays, and cannot be reassigned to different memory locations (but their content may change, use `const` to avoid that).

Comment: `char p3[5] = "String";` while dangerous is not wrong and it is valid in C (but not in C++)

Comment: @ouah - it is wrong. It may pass compilation, but it is nevertheless **wrong**.

Comment: this is a strictly conforming definition for an object. A strictly conforming program is not "wrong" in terms of C.

Comment: @ouah Blatant runtime errors are wrong.

Comment: @Chris, Depends on the other statements doesn't it. There isn't necessarily a runtime error.

Comment: @Pacerier it depends on many things, but at the end of the day it's still considered undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is not deterministic, which is still a runtime error even if the program doesn't crash from it.

Comment: @Chris, That's provided the code even gets **run**-ed at runtime. Surely **compiling** that code alone wouldn't give you undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pacerier undefined always refers to runtime behavior. It will indeed compile.

Comment: @Chris, And that's why we wouldn't have undefined behavior is that compiled code doesn't get run, for example when its surrounded within an `if` statement that doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: @Pacerier I really am having a hard time following this conversation. No, runtime errors don't occur if you skip over the problematic code.

Comment: @Chris, Yes, that's what I've been saying all along... You stated *"Blatant runtime errors are wrong."* so I stated *"Depends on the other statements doesn't it. There isn't necessarily a runtime error."*.  Runtime errors don't occur if you skip over the problematic code so depending on the other statements, there isn't necessarily a runtime error.

Comment: @Pacerier please stop being intentionally pedantic. You know very well that my statement  doesn't mean 'renders the program useless'. The surrounding code is irrelevant. If I write to memory that I shouldn't write to, that's bad behavior. That's a bug. Even if no one notices, that's still a bug. Even if my code never runs, there's still a bug present. The bug may not run, but that doesn't mean my code is bug-free. Stop with the games, you're not being clever.

Answer (score 7):

```
char *p = "String";   means pointer to a string type variable.
```

`char p3[5] = "String"`;  means you are pre-defining the size of the array to consist of no more than 5 elements. Note that,for strings the null "\0" is also considered as an element.So,this statement would give an error since the number of elements is 7 so it should be:

```
char p3[7]= "String";
```