# Segmentation fault when reversing string in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which its main purpose is reverse the characters of a string. So, for example, the string `I love cats` would be converted to `stac evol I`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseString(char *str)
{
   int size = strlen(str);
   char *end = str + size - 1;
   char tmp;

   while (end > str) {
     tmp = *str;
     *str = *end;
     *end = tmp;
     end--;
     str++;
   }
}

int main()
{
  char *str = "Y U SEGMENTATION FAULT?";
  reverseString(str);

}
```

When I run this, I get a segmentation fault, and I fail to see why.  Also, another question I have is the time complexity (Big O) of this function.  I believe it should be O(n/2), since I am not going through all the array but just the half of it. Am I right?

Comment: `O(n/2) == O(0.5 * n) == O(c * n) == O(n)`, so reversing a String is in `O(n)`

Comment: `char str[] = "Y U SEGMENTATION FAULT?";`

Comment: I am really sorry. I didn't see that other question. It's a duplicate yes.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before that I'm surprised that the automatic search didn't return any results.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a character literal, a string in read only data segment. Make a copy/duplicate  of it on the heap with strdup, for example:

```
char *str = strdup("It's OK now");
```

Or make it a local array (place the string on the stack):

```
char[] str = "It's OK now";
```

Comment: But according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732325/how-to-declare-strings-in-c -- If I declare my string with a pointer, I can modify it, right?

Comment: No, you can declare your string as a local array, as hmjd suggested, that will be a different story.

Comment: @HommerSmith One of the differences between `char *foo = "bar";` and `char foo[] = "bar";` is the method of initialisation. The former converts the read only array to a pointer and stores the pointer. The latter *copies* the read only array into a new modifiable array.