# Expression syntax error in the following code

Tags: c

```
char name[25]; 
name[] = "abcd";
```

The code above gives me expression syntax error.

```
char name[25]; 
name = "abcd";
```

The code above gives me an Lvalue Required error.

But following code gives no error:

```
char name[25] = "abcd";
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Initialization and assignment are not the same thing

Comment: (1) You can't assign to arrays, and the `name[]` notation is only valid in an array declaration or definition.  (2) You still can't assign arrays.  (3) You can initialize arrays.

Comment: You can see this topic to have answers :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732325/how-to-declare-strings-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732325/how-to-declare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char name[25]` (a declaration of an array) does this:

- Reserves 25 bytes of memory
- Declares `name` as an array of characters (which is almost but not exactly like `char *`) pointing to that memory.

`char name[25] = "abcd"` (a declaration of an array with an initialiser) does this:

- Reserves 25 bytes of memory, filled with `"abcd\0"`
- Declares `name` as an array of characters (which is almost but not exactly like `char *`) pointing to that memory.

(The case of `name[] = "abcd"` is not a syntax supported by C.)

In both cases, one of the critical differences between pointers and arrays is that the target of a pointer can change; the target of an array cannot. I.e. you can never assign anything to `name` declared as `char[]` above, but you can assign to `name` declared as `char *`, as follows. `char *name; name = "abcd"` (a declaration of a pointer, assignment of a literal character array to a pointer) does this:

- Reserves 5 bytes of memory, filled by `"abcd\0"`
- Declares `name` as a pointer to character (which is almost but not exactly like `char[]`) pointing to undefined target
- Assigns the address of the memory occupied by `"abcd\0"` to the variable `name`.

Answer (score 3):

If to place semicolons as it is required then this construction

```
char name[25]; name[]="abcd";
```

may be rewritten for visibility like

```
char name[25]; 
name[]="abcd";
```

So iy is seen that in the second line there us absent a type specifier that the line would be a valid declaration

```
char name[25]; 
char name[]="abcd";
```

In this line where again there is absent a type specifier for the second identifier

```
char name[25]; name ="abcd"
```

and we will rewrite like

```
char name[25]; 
char name ="abcd";
```

then `name` has the type `char` but is initialized by a string literal instead of one character. So it is evident that name shall be an array or a pointer to char, For example

```
char name[25]; 
char name[] ="abcd";
```

or

```
char name[25]; 
char *name ="abcd";
```

or for example

```
char name[25]; 
char name[26] ="abcd";
```

Of course the names of identifiers shall be different. Otherwise the compiler again will issue an error due to redefinition of the same identifier name in the same scope.

Comment: @Deb Please reread my answer one more. You need to use different names of the declarations in the same scope.