# Assigning different inputs to different structure variables in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how I can assign different inputs to different structure variables. For example, if one user inputs his/her name then it gets assigned to `p1.name`, and if the next person inputs his/her name it gets assigned to `p2.name` and so on.

```
struct patient {
    int number;
    char name;
    char status;
    char medications;
    float bill;
};

struct patient p1, p2, p3;
printf("Name: ");
scanf("%c", &pname);
```

Comment: Did you mean `&(p1.name)`? Also, did you mean to use a loop and an array of structures: `struct patient patients[x];`?

Comment: Use an array that you can index.

Comment: Note that `char` is just a single character. Check out the "string handling" topic in your C tutorial if you want to handle actual names. Further, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To store names, you should use `char` arrays (strings):

```
struct patient {
    char name[51];
    // ...
};
```

To get patients in a row, use a loop:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_PATIENTS  10
// ...
struct patient patients[NUMBER_OF_PATIENTS];
// ...
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PATIENTS; i++) {
    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(patients[i].name, 50, stdin);
    // ...
}
```

Also, `scanf("%c", &ch)` reads a single character, not a string. You should look up C strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732449/1928852).

Answer (score 0):

For numeric types, you'd use the `&` operator with the structure name and the `.` member selection operator:

```
scanf( "%d", &p1.number );
scanf( "%f", &p1.bill );
```

For *strings*, you first need to declare each member as an *array* of `char`:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 40
#define MAX_STATUS_LEN 20
#define MAX_MEDICATION_LEN 100

struct patient
{
  ...
  char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1]; // plus 1 for string terminator
  char status[MAX_STATUS_LEN+1];
  char medications[MAX_MEDICATION_LEN+1];
  ...
};
```

then you should read each string using `fgets`:

```
if ( !fgets( p1.name, sizeof p1.name, stdin ) )
  // error on read
```

You *could* use `scanf` to read string inputs, but it requires some work to make it secure.  It's just easier and safer to use `fgets`.

One quirk of `fgets` is that it stores the trailing newline to the buffer if there's room, so you will want to add a couple of checks for it.  If it is present, you probably want to remove it so it doesn't cause problems.  If it *isn't* present, then you probably want to consume any remaining input in the input stream so it doesn't foul up the next read:

```
char *newline = strchr( p1.name, '\n' );
if ( newline )
  *newline = 0;
else
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ; // empty loop body
```