# Difference between string created by array and pointer?

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

What is the difference between this:

```
char arr[] = "Hello, world!";
```

And this:

```
char *arr = "Hello, world!";
```

Where do both strings' memory get allocated? Why am I not able to change content of latter string?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the latter should read `const char *arr = "hello world!";`

Comment: @Nemo: It *should*, but strictly speaking C doesn't require it.  C string literals are not `const`, but attempting to modify one is undefined behavior

Comment: @teacher: This question has been asked many times on SO. A quick search gave these links. 
(a) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c
(b) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880573/c-difference-between-char-var-and-char-var

Answer (score 5):

The first one is writable memory allocated specifically for `arr`, which is an array of `char`s. You can modify it without invoking *undefined behavior*. This is completely legal:

```
char arr[] = "Hello, world!";
arr[1] = 'i';
```

The second one is a pointer to a read-only string. Therefore, this is *undefined behavior*:

```
char *parr = "Hello, world!";
parr[1] = 'i'; // Cannot write to read-only memory!
```

---

In *some* compiler implementations:

```
char *a = "Hello, world!";
char *b = "Hello, world!";

a[1] = 'i';
// b[1] == 'i';
```

**This isn't guaranteed** - I'm only including it to give you an 'intuitive' feel of why it's *undefined* behavior.

Comment: are both strings created on stack?

Comment: No, the read-only string is stored in a read-only part of the memory of you're process.

Comment: @teacher: depends on where you declare it, and in the second example the actual string is in readonly memory.

Comment: @Ed S. i am using both inside a function...

Comment: @teacher - `arr` resides on stack but the value pointed by `arr` resides on read only location whose location is implementation dependent.

Comment: err..No one mentions Second is called a **String Literal**?

Comment: @Mehash: No, the contents of `arr` resides on the stack.  Otherwise it would be not be modifiable.

Comment: For the char* case you can actually do parr[i] = 'i'; but on some compilers it will print the original string :)

Comment: @Jesus: For the char* case, `parr[i] = 'i'` has undefined behavior.  It can cause your program to crash (if you're lucky).

Comment: @Als: In both cases `"hello, world"` is a string literal.

Comment: @Keith just tried in GCC, doesn't crash and prints the original string http://ideone.com/xtf9r

Comment: @Jesus: That's one of the infinitely many possible results of undefined behavior.  I just tried this with gcc: `char *s = "hello, world"; s[0] = 'H';` and the program died with a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Keith hence the undefined part, I was just bringing up a point that it may seem like an odd bug if that occurs because of the behavior and the person not understanding how it works.