# Getting Segmentation Fault in String Manipulation

Tags: c, string

Here i give input string like this `"/org/bluez/1509/hci0"`

And i want output like this `/org/bluez/1509/hci0`

Here i use this method but i got Segmentation fault.

```
void main () 
{
    char  *str = "\"/org/bluez/1509/hci0\"";
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("\nlength %d\n",len);
   char *str1;
   str1 = str+1;
   printf("String 1 = %s\n",str1);
   *(str1+ (strlen(str)-2)) = '\0'; 
   printf("\nString 1 = %s\n",str1);
}
```

I am getting output like this

```
length 22
String 1 = /org/bluez/1509/hci0"
Segmentation fault
```

Problem with Last " character.

Can Any body Help me or Suggest me new Way.?

Comment: string literals are not modifiable. Try copying it to an array: `char str[] = "\"/org/bluez/1509/hci0\"";`. Also `main` returns an integer; change that `void`, and add a `return 0;` if you want C89 compatability (also need to declare all variables before any code statement).

Comment: I suggest changing `*(str1+ (strlen(str)-2)) = '\0';` to `str1[ strlen(str1) - 1 ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
char str[] = "\"/org/bluez/1509/hci0\"";
```

Instead of a pointer. The pointer only "points" to the string literal which is not modifiable. You can read more about this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880588/557306) and a ton of other similar ones. It's even in the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html), take a look on it!