# Difference between char* and char[] in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C - Difference between “char var[]” and “char *var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880573/c-difference-between-char-var-and-char-var)

I have written the following C code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[31];
    char *temp;
    int i ;
    scanf("%s",name);
    temp  = name;
    name = temp;

}
```

I got the following error when compiling

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[31]' from type 'char *'
```

Array `name` is a pointer to first element(here char pointer ..right?). right? The above code  means that character array and `char*` are different types ..Is it true?
Why is the type of `name != char *`?
Why can I assign another `char` pointer to a `char` pointer (the `name` array)?

Comment: Please have a look into the C FAQ before asking a question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Array name is a pointer to first element(here char pointer ..right?). right?"

```
char name[31];
char *temp;
/* ... */
name = temp;
```

In the `name =  temp` assignment, the value of `name` is converted to a pointer to `char`. The value is converted, **not** the object. The object is still an array and arrays are not modifiable lvalues.  As the constraints of the assignment operand require the left operand of the assignment operator to be a modifiable lvalue, you got an error.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why you downvoted this answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Array name is a pointer to first element(here char pointer ..right?).
>   right?

Wrong. Arrays *decay* to a pointer to the first element in most contexts, but they certainly aren't pointers. There's a good explanation in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) and an invaluable picture (a is an array and p is a pointer):

[image: Arrays and pointers]

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[31]' from type 'char
>   *'

In C arrays are non-modifiable lvalues, you can't change what they point to since they **don't point anywhere in the first place**.

Comment: Ok...got the point arrays are non modifiable lvalues...That means

 i cannot also do 

char name[31];
    char temp[31];
    int i ;

       scanf("%s",name);

    temp  = name;
    name = temp;
right?

...Also how to indent code in when i comment here ? :)

Comment: The scanf is almost ok (drop the &). The rest is wrong.

Comment: why the rest is wrong?
It also gives the same error on gcc

Answer (score 1):

First, arrays are memory buffers, not pointers, although they might be decayed to pointers when needed.

Now, `name`is an array, so you cannot assign to it. when you assign an array to a pointer, the array is decayed to a pointer, and the assignment is valid.

Comment: This is new information for me...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the pointer points towards an object of the same type. This means a pointer can be used as a fully fledged array if it's allocated properly.
A NON pointer means you have the data here "in front of you", which doesn't let you properly get the data  (also has time-of-life problems), so to be honest, pointers are better to be used everywhere in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'name' is an array. So 
This line:

```
name = temp;
```

will give you error.

Also your condition in the for loop is wrong. name[] will have junk values and you can't use

```
name[i]!='\0'
```

as a condition.