# incompatible types in assignment of char * to char[200]

Tags: c, split

Execute main, it will ask for input.

Store input in the argbuf.

Then, use strwrd to split argbuf into tokens

Yet, it says "Error: incompatible   types in assignment of char * to char[200]"

I cannot figure out why..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char argbuf[200];//used to store input

char *strwrd(char *s, char *buf, size_t len, char *delim){
    s += strcspn(s, delim);
    int n = strcspn(s, delim); /* count the span (spn) of bytes in */
    if (len-1 < n)             /* the complement (c) of *delim */
        n = len-1;
    memcpy(buf, s, n);
    buf[n] = 0;
    s += n;
    return (*s == 0) ? NULL : s;
}



int main(){
    fgets(argbuf, sizeof(argbuf), stdin);
    char token[10][20];
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        argbuf = strwrd(argbuf, token[index], sizeof(token[index]), " \t");
        if (argbuf == NULL)
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that. I always try to answer questions...but, i am new to programming...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between char* and char\[\] in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054271/difference-between-char-and-char-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strwrd` returns a `char*`, so you can't store this value in a `char[200]` variable. Use `char*` type instead.

Comment: I think "argbuf" represents the address of argbuf[200]?

Comment: You've declared argbuf as an array, so at times it's appropriate to treat it like a char*. But here, you can't return a char* into argbuf because it's immobile in memory.

Comment: I declared another pointer "char *buf=NULL". and assign the address of the array to buf "buf=argbuf". Then, use the buf as the parameter of strwrd. Finally, it works.

Answer (score 1):

`char *` and `char[x]` are different types, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)

[Here's another good resource](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/)

In your code `char argbuf[200];` is a statically allocated array, so you can not assign a pointer to it. Why pass the global back and forth anyway? If you're going to use argbuf as a global variable then just modify it inside strwrd directly if your each for '\t' comes back with something valid.