# C "__builtin_types_compatible_p" function is returning the wrong value for "char*" type

Tags: c, types, built-in

`__builtin_types_compatible_p` is a function that is supposed to compare two types and return true if they are equal or false if they are not the same type.  For some reason this doesn't seem to be working when I am dealing with `char*` types.

example:

```
printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(1), int));
printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof("thing"), char *));
```

These two lines will produce the output:

```
1
0
```

Which suggests that `"thing"` is not of type `char*` which is just not true... How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: I didn't even know about that function. +1. I also answered the question. :)

Comment: It would be worth if you know the difference between char * and char * const types.

Comment: @manavm-n, It says in the documentation that it doesn't recognize a difference between char* and const char*.  But I was unaware that char* and char[] are treated as different types. see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is correct; a string literal is of type: `char[]`**. `char*` and `char[]` *are different types*.

---

Check it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(1), int));
        printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof("thing"), char[]));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

---

Appendix:

1. [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-c)
2. [Char array vs Char Pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)
3. [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
4. [Difference between char* and char[] in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054271/difference-between-char-and-char-in-c)

Comment: Actually, looks like the function does not do fully strict type comparsion. If it works in C same as in C++, then `"thing"` has type `char [6]`. And `char []` is a different type (an array of unknown bound).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not sure if it works the same. It would be a nice follow-up question.